# Выравнивание формы

Tags: java

Нужно создать форму регистрации, чисто визуально, и я не знаю как выровнять ее элементы. Располагаться они должны так: название поля - рядом само поле, и так в каждой строке
код:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Registration extends JDialog {
    private final JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Ф.И.О: ");
    private final JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Адрес: ");
    private final JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Город: ");
    private final JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Почтовый индекс: ");
    private final JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Телефон: ");
    private final JLabel label6 = new JLabel("Дополнительная информация: ");
    private final JLabel label7 = new JLabel("E-mail: ");
    private final JLabel label8 = new JLabel("Пароль: ");
    private final JLabel label9 = new JLabel("Повторите пароль: ");

    private final JTextField field1 = new JTextField(40);
    private final JTextField field2 = new JTextField(40);
    private final JTextField field3 = new JTextField(40);
    private final JTextField field4 = new JTextField(40);
    private final JTextField field5 = new JTextField(40);
    private final JTextField field6 = new JTextField(40);

    private final JTextArea text = new JTextArea();

    private final JPasswordField password1 = new JPasswordField();
    private final JPasswordField password2 = new JPasswordField();

    private final Checkbox checkBox = new Checkbox("Я хочу получать новости и спецпредложения");

    public Registration() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(700, 700);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    JPanel grid = new JPanel();
    grid.setLayout(new BoxLayout(grid, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    grid.add(label1);
    grid.add(field1);
    grid.add(label2);
    grid.add(field2);
    grid.add(label3);
    grid.add(field3);
    grid.add(label4);
    grid.add(field4);
    grid.add(label5);
    grid.add(field5);
    grid.add(label6);
    grid.add(text);
    grid.add(label7);
    grid.add(field6);
    grid.add(label8);
    grid.add(password1);
    grid.add(label9);
    grid.add(password2);
    //grid.add(checkBox);
    frame.add(grid);

}

}
public class FlowLayoutTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Registration forma = new Registration();
    }
}
```

и да, выравнивание PAGE_AXIS, которое я использовала, работает не так, как мне нужно

Comment: у вас fx или swing?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать GridLayout

```
class Registration extends JDialog {
private final JLabel lblFIO = new JLabel("Ф.И.О: ");
private final JLabel lblAddress = new JLabel("Адрес: ");
private final JLabel lblCity = new JLabel("Город: ");
private final JLabel lblMailIndex = new JLabel("Почтовый индекс: ");
private final JLabel lblPhone = new JLabel("Телефон: ");
private final JLabel lblAdditionalInfo = new JLabel("Дополнительная информация: ");
private final JLabel lblEmail = new JLabel("E-mail: ");
private final JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Пароль: ");
private final JLabel lblConfirmPassword = new JLabel("Повторите пароль: ");

private final JTextField fldFIO = new JTextField(40);
private final JTextField fldAddress = new JTextField(40);
private final JTextField fldCity = new JTextField(40);
private final JTextField fldMailIndex = new JTextField(40);
private final JTextField fldPhone = new JTextField(40);
private final JTextArea textAdditionalInfo = new JTextArea();
private final JTextField fldEmail = new JTextField(40);
private final JPasswordField password1 = new JPasswordField();
private final JPasswordField password2 = new JPasswordField();

private final Checkbox checkBox = new Checkbox("Я хочу получать новости и спецпредложения");

public Registration() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(570, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel grid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(9,2,5,5));
    Dimension lblDim = new Dimension(200,21);
    lblFIO.setMaximumSize(lblDim);
    lblAddress.setMaximumSize(lblDim);
    lblCity.setMaximumSize(lblDim);
    lblMailIndex.setMaximumSize(lblDim);
    lblPhone.setMaximumSize(lblDim);
    lblAdditionalInfo.setMaximumSize(lblDim);
    lblEmail.setMaximumSize(lblDim);
    lblPassword.setMaximumSize(lblDim);
    lblConfirmPassword.setMaximumSize(lblDim);

    Dimension fldDim = new Dimension(200,21);
    fldFIO.setMaximumSize(fldDim);
    fldAddress.setMaximumSize(fldDim);
    fldCity.setMaximumSize(fldDim);
    fldMailIndex.setMaximumSize(fldDim);
    fldPhone.setMaximumSize(fldDim);

    textAdditionalInfo.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,100));

    fldEmail.setMaximumSize(fldDim);
    password1.setMaximumSize(fldDim);
    password2.setMaximumSize(fldDim);


    grid.add(lblFIO);
    grid.add(fldFIO);
    grid.add(lblAddress);
    grid.add(fldAddress);
    grid.add(lblCity);
    grid.add(fldCity);
    grid.add(lblMailIndex);
    grid.add(fldMailIndex);
    grid.add(lblPhone);
    grid.add(fldPhone);
    grid.add(lblAdditionalInfo);
    grid.add(new JScrollPane(textAdditionalInfo,ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER));
    grid.add(lblEmail);
    grid.add(fldEmail);
    grid.add(lblPassword);
    grid.add(password1);
    grid.add(lblConfirmPassword);
    grid.add(password2);
    //grid.add(checkBox);
    frame.add(grid);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}}
```

[image: Результат]

[Oracle: How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)